# In how many ways we can create unique pairs of two numbers from $[1,9]$, such that the difference between them is never $1$?

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

In how many ways we can form unique pairs of two numbers ( referring to integers ), such that, a mod of the difference of two numbers in pair is never equal to $1$ i.e $\{(a, b): |b-a| \neq 1\}$ and the number in the pair is in the interval $[1, 9]$? I need unique pairs, $(a,b)$ is considered same as $(b, a)$

I'm struggling to even begin thinking about it, here is what I'm thinking
so $1$ and $9$ are different than others as they don't have two neighbors that might result in the difference being $1$, so I have two cases

Case 1: in $[2,8]$, we will have to avoid values less and greater than these.

Case 2: For $1$, and $9$, we will have $7$ intgegers to pair with,

How do I approach after that? I'm struggling to put this in the combinatorial formula. what should I choose and from which? If you can explain this, that would be great. I can't use any other method.

Comment: I don't understand.  Seems like a simple count, even if you enumerate by hand.  If the least element is $1$, how many choices have you got for the largest?  What if the least element is $2$?  Or have I misunderstood the problem?

Comment: Alternatively, count all the ways to choose two distinct, unordered, pairs and subtract off those pairs that differ by $1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:**

[image: Visual proof]

1. We count only **the upper triangular half** since we have $(a,b)$ equivalent to $(b,a)$.
2. Numbers of the form $(a,a+1)$ are excluded (highlighted in light red) since the digit absolute difference equals 1
3. Numbers of the form $(a,a)$, if permitted, are on the main diagonal.

Comment: I got 28
, ${9\choose2} - 8$

Comment: The upper triangle, including the main diagonal, has $\frac{9 \cdot 10}{2} = 45$ entries. The cells highlighted in red (in the upper triangular half) have absolute difference $1$ and are to be excluded. There are $8$ of those. The cells in orange are pairs with identical choices. I am considering them a *unique* pair and are permitted. If they are not permitted then you should exclude the orange cells also which are $9$ in number.

Comment: @Ace: Your answer is right if you don't permit pairs of the form $(a,a)$. It wasn't obvious from the question as the digit difference is $0$ (which is $\ne 1$ as required).

Comment: you are absolutely correct, it's actually allowed for difference to be zero, it must not be 1, and we will have to use, "combination with repetation"  so ${10 \choose 2} - 8 = 37$

Answer (score 0):

If you are counting the number of 2-subsets of $[1,9]$ that the difference between 2 elements is not $1$.

Here is the Mathematica code. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78/78gMbOoWMFWIbg0qTi1pDg6KDEvPTXaUEfBMlZHodqoNtaayyc1L70kwwGsUl8/oCgzr4QrLTOnJLUoNSUApj01JzW5JBqsRkfBMak4Wjk62jA2VkFXAcgwigWyFG0VDBXU4OZFoxgRCzX4/38A)

```
pairs = Subsets[Range[1, 9], {2}];
Length@pairs//Print
filteredPairs = Select[pairs, Abs[#[[1]] - #[[2]]] != 1 &];
Length[filteredPairs]//Print
```

$$
\color{red}{28}
$$